# Will my salah be accepted if i do Ghsul right after masterbation?

Tags: salat, ghusl, masturbation

I am getting into Islam but I'm finding it hard to quit masterbation so I am wondering if I can do ghsul right after I finish masterbating. if I can then I think I can become a full Muslim inshallah!

Comment: @muslimpro56, this is bad comment

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is will be accepted inshaAllah. Repent to Allah and make a firm intention not to repeat the sin. Allah says:

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by
> sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allāh. Indeed, Allāh forgives
> all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." Quran
> (39:53)